# Error: Permission denied - /usr/share/logstash/sincedb/sincedb

Tags: docker-compose, logstash

I have a `docker-compose` file for running several containers including Logstash. I have mapped the mounted `sincedb` as in the snippet:

```
logstash:
build:
  context: logstash/
volumes:      
  - ./tmp/logstash/sincedb:/usr/share/logstash/sincedb
```

The Logstash container has some permission errors, in particular with accessing sincedb as shown in the error snippet below:

```
Error: Permission denied - /usr/share/logstash/sincedb/sincedb
Exception: Errno::EACCES
```

I tried to execute within the container chmod but I get some the errors below:

```
bash-4.2$ chmod o+wx /usr/share/logstash/sincedb/
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/share/logstash/sincedb/’: Operation not permitted
```

Is there a way to overcome this permission issue ?

Comment: try to use docker named volume, maybe you have bad permission on your host ./tmp folder

Comment: @MazelTov can you give an example or a reference how i can do this. I think my approach already used `docker named volumes` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by setting proper permissions to the host folder, which maps to the folder in the docker container. By issuing the command `chmod -R 757` against the folder, access was possible. However, this was a temporary measure, I later discovered the correct permissions can be set in the `docker-compose.yml` file by appending `:rw` at the end of the specific line, like so :

```
 volumes:
  - logstash_data:/usr/share/logstash/sincedb:rw
```

This effectively maintained the permissions across rebuilds, which is a limitation of the earlier mentioned method (additional to the security implications)

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use docker named volumes. Currently you are just mounting host folder to the container

Sample docker-compose.yml with named volumes

```
version: '3.5'
services:  
  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
    volumes:
      - logstash_data:/usr/share/logstash/sincedb

volumes:
  logstash_data: # optionaly define more parameters
```

then you can see the named volume with command

```
docker volume ls
```